# Can Doxygen be integrated with Netbeans C++?

Tags: c++, netbeans, doxygen

I've been reading up on Doxygen online, and I think I'd like to try it out on my Netbeans C++ projects. The problem is, I cannot find any tutorials/guides anywhere to how to get Doxygen working with Netbeans. I've found some blog posts that seem to be about using Doxygen in Netbeans, but they seem semi-feature requesty, and I cannot tell if they are actual guides or just "this is what it should look like when it is done" posts. So, does anyone here have any experience of working with Doxygen and Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for support from IDE to use Doxygen, you can use them separately. To create Doxygen documentation you just need a source code and Doxygen compiler.

However IDE can serve some kind of support. Netbeans allows you quickly create a comment (see [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=171326)). That's the only support I know.

There is also [plug-in "Doxygen Integration"](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=14326) but I never used it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I installed Doxygen and have managed to get it working via command-line. Was unable to get Doxygen Integration working - when I run it Netbeans just hangs, but thank you for the link to that too.